# When using redirect_to files on s3. How to either display an image or download a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3 AttachmentsController, I have the following:

```
  def show
    attachment = Attachment.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to(attachment.authenticated_url())
  end
```

Where authenticated_url is simply a URL to S3 to access the file.

The problem is that the file is always downloaded by the browser. What I would like to have happen is if the file is an image/pdf, something the browser can render, show the file in the browser and only download non-browser friendly files.

Have you seen this before? Any ideas on where to start?

Thanks

Comment: what about redirecting to a template and in there put a link_to the file or you must show the file immediately?

Answer (score 5):

send_file can be used for remote url as well

```
file = open("http://cdn2.example.com/somefile.pdf")
send_file(file, :filename => "example.pdf", :type => "application/pdf" , :disposition => "attachment")
```

Here example.pdf will be downloaded. If you want open pdf in browser itself use this

```
file = open("http://cdn2.example.com/somefile.pdf")
send_file(file, :filename => "example.pdf", :type => "application/pdf" , :disposition => "inline")
```

Comment: Thanks, does this actually download the file to the rails server first?

Comment: If so that's a huge performance hit for files that can be 1gig. I'm using Rails 3 with Paperclip/S3. I'm trying to find a way to see if I can set the s3_headers in paperclip to something to tell the browser to display inline. Ideas?

Comment: yeah...It is always recommended to use disposition as inline when you open remote file. Because as you said if the file size is 1GB it first downloads in rails server temporarily and open in browser.
you can use =link_to as @Xiao feng Zha suggested

Comment: ok so that won't work, I can't be having the app servers do all the downloading work. That's blocking. Trying to find a way to get s3/paperclip to render inline

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to @attachment.url
```

I'm using Paperclip as well, and this display pictures inside the browser. Do you have to do something different than this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll want to look into the rails send_file method.

1)  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file

The :disposition option lets you decide whether a file will be downloaded or displayed inline.  I used this in my rails app to let users download mp3 files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for send file only handle local files not remote/urls correct?